# How to set text at the center right position?

Tags: android, textview

I am using a text view, and its width is matching the parent. I want to set its text to centre right position. If I use `android:gravity="right"` then why does it move to the upper right position?

I am using this:

```
 <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:textSize="12sp"
           android:textStyle="bold" />
```

I have tried this many times, but I could not get good results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `android:padding` to match your requirements. Also use `android:gravity="center|right"`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `android:gravity` property with pipeline<kbd>|</kbd>, setting the property to Center as well as Right position.

```
android:gravity="center|right"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use centre gravity like this:

```
android:gravity="center|right"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `android:gravity="right|center_vertical"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" 
                        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"   />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
```

want to align horizontal: `android:gravity="right|center_horizontal"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
android:gravity="canter"
```

And then use

```
android:paddingLeft="<your value>"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center the text with respect to the layout, use `android:layout_gravity="center"`, but if you just want the letter to center with respect to the whole word, use `android:gravity="center"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. It will work.

```
android:gravity="center"
```